# Write OutputStream To Excel in chunks

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have a requirement where i need to generate reports of around millions of records and later export it to Excel. am using jasper reports for the purpose. Am able to preview the report. But when i try to export the report to Excel, getting Heap Memory error. But am able to get the entire dataset in the ByteArrayOutputStream object. After a long Googling came to a conclusion that it is common if the data is so huge. So i decided to write the data to excel chunk by chunk. But how to achieve that? How to divide the data and how to write data to excel part by part so that the final output file is a consolidated one. Please suggest.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use "poi" instead of jasper reports?
Poi is a library for Microsoft Documents by Apache. Link: http://poi.apache.org/

In this library there is a class called "SXSSFWorkbook" that uses streaming technology. Read the javadoc for more information: http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html